# Error calling lmFit (limma) in an R package

Tags: r, package

I am including a call to `lmFit` in a new-private R package. But when calling the method that includes the call to `lmFit` I got an error:

```
Error in getEAWP(object) : could not find function "exprs"
```

The implemented structure follows:

```
setMethod(
  f = "genexp",
  signature = "clusterContainer",
  definition = function(object, expSet, fdr.cutoff = 0.05) {

    design <- model.matrix(groups, data = Biobase::pData(expSet))
    fit <- limma::lmFit(expSet, design)
    fit <- limma::eBayes(fit)
    # [...]
  }
)
```

The `DESCRIPTION` file contains:

```
...
LazyData: true
Imports:
  Biobase,
  ...
  limma
Suggests:
  testthat
```

And the `NAMESPACE`:

```
exportPattern("^[^\\.]")
importFrom(Biobase, AnnotatedDataFrame)
importFrom(Biobase, exprs)
```

What I need to do to call `lmFit` (and others) and let them use functionality of third packages?

**UPDATE 1**: I add the traceback:

```
> genexp(c, expression)
 Error in getEAWP(object) : could not find function "exprs" 
5 getEAWP(object) 
4 limma::lmFit(expSet, design) at clusterContainer-genexp.R#18
3 .local(object, ...) 
2 genexp(c, expression) at 1_AllGenerics.R#50
1 genexp(c, expression)
```

**UPDATE 2**: The function `getEAWP` is from `limma`. The function `exprs` is from `Biobase`.

Comment: A solution could be to add `Biobase` into the `Depends` section on `DESCRIPTION` file. But I think it is not the right solution.

Comment: Is `getEAWP` in the limma package or elsewhere? (you can try `limma:::expers` to see if it's in that package.)  I'm guessing it's in another package, and that it's not qualified (e.g. `otherPackage::expers`) in the function `limma::lmFit`.   Perhaps adding `otherPackage` to your Depends section in the `DESCRIPTION` file and calling library('otherPackage')` will solve this problem.

Comment: Thanks @Jthorpe for your comment, I updated the question trying to clarify the situation. `exprs` is from `Biobase` and I had it in my `Imports` section (at `DESCRIPTION` file). The only solution I found is to move `Bioase` to `Depends` but I still think it is not a good solution.

Comment: Well,it sure looks like your package *does* depend on `Biobase` so why not `Depends` ?  If you explicitly add `require(Biobase)` to your code,does it run?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft, adding the `require(Biobase)` in the method makes it runnable. So, for that, should I include the `Biobase` on `Depends`?

Comment: I think so, but I'm not an expert on interdependent packages